# What is the actual origin of the aphorism about intentions and capabilities?

Tags: выражения, этимология

UPDATE: It turns out that even Russia's president Vladimir Putin himself quoted Bismarck as saying that phrase! ([Source1](https://snob.ru/selected/entry/86685), [Source2](https://irrussianality.wordpress.com/2017/12/16/crackpot-theory-no-9-assume-the-worst)). It thus seems unlikely to be a made-up quotation, because it is unthinkable that the Russian president will use made-up quotations. I am very much curious to find the original German phrase and its context and spent a few more hours searching, but found nothing. That's a real mystery...

---

Reading an article for my Russian classes, I saw a quotation from Otto von Bismarck:

> Но еще Отто фон Бисмарк сказал: "Меня не интересуют их намерения, меня интересуют их возможности". ([Source](https://www.pravda.ru/world/1060976-agressor))

The quotation as it stands in Russian is so ruthless, cynical, and thought-stimulating that I got really curious what Bismarck actually said in German and whether he said anything like that at all.

I did a lot of research and was unable to find any trace to the German original, but found that the above quotation is very frequently used in the Russian language as an aphorism attributed to Bismarck, as there are hundreds of hits in Google, [quite a few hits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%22) in Google Books, and even a [hit](http://duma.gov.ru/media/files/kXzQ8bic0Clk5M49oo85LMvbq3RQpoyr.pdf) in minutes of the Russian Parliament. There are also rephrasings, e.g.:

> ... но еще Бисмарк сказал: "В политике важны не намерения, а возможности. Намерения меняются, возможности остаются". ([Source](http://politrussia.com/vooruzhennye-sily/vasserman-20-226/))

I have been unable to find any similar aphorism in German, English, or Japanese. I even asked a [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53588) on the German SE and a [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/53951) on the History SE in an attempt to find the original German phrase by Bismarck, but no one has been able to help me so far. For some mysterious reason this aphorism appears to be popular exclusively in the Russian language.

My question is this: What is the actual origin of this Russian aphorism attributed to Bismarck?

Comment: I saw this aphorism to be attributed to Napolean, Roosevelt and some other famous figures. I am sure someone sad this ones, but I am not shure who. Basicly this aphorism is used in Russian public politics to show that West wants to destroy us whatever we do, just becase they afriad of us. And public politics is not the most honorable thing in universe. As A.S.Pushking were saying - never trust citations on the internets!

Comment: @ksbes: Doing my research, I saw this aphorism being attributed exclusively to Bismarck. Can you show me any websites attributing the aphorism to anyone else?

Comment: @ksbes : It does not seem very likely to be a made-up quotation. The  idea expressed in the quotation strongly resonates with Bismark's views as I can see in this history article: https://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/full/10.1162/isec_a_00323

Comment: I quote from that article: *The most important constraint in international relations is, of course, the distribution of power. For structural realists, power is called capability. The term itself is etymologically derivative of “ability,” which implies what can, as opposed to what cannot, be done*.

Comment: I also highly doubt that a member of the Russian parliament and popular Russian analysts would use a totally made-up quotation.

Comment: I don't want to say this phrase is fake. I want to say that its might be just widly misattributed to Bismark, like «Франко-прусскую войну выиграл немецкий школьный учитель» (https://trv-science.ru/2014/10/21/vspomnim-bismarka/), or much more famous aphorism attributed to Lenin «Любая кухарка может управлять государством» (who actualy said exactly the opposite). They are widly used by Russian politicians for so long time, that  people think this attribution to be obvious.

Comment: I've sent an email to [N.A.Vlasov](https://elibrary.ru/author_items.asp?authorid=248421) the author of [this article](https://elibrary.ru/item.asp?id=28408926) asking if he can comment on the OP's quotation.

Comment: Got the reply, now waiting for his permission to post his opinion on this resource.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about Russian language, but rather about the origins of a phrase attributed to a German political figure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've sent an email to [N.A.Vlasov](https://elibrary.ru/author_items.asp?authorid=248421) the author of [this article](https://elibrary.ru/item.asp?id=28408926) asking him to comment on the quotation from the question.

Here is the response in full:

> Добрый день!
>
> Однозначно утверждать, что Бисмарк этого не говорил, я не возьмусь. В
>   огромном массиве его писем, речей, разговоров и т.д. могла встретиться
>   такая фраза - но по конкретному вопросу и в конкретном контексте, вне
>   которого ее рассматривать бессмысленно. Расценивать такое
>   высказывание, если оно и имело место, как некий общий принцип, которым
>   руководствовался Бисмарк, попросту невозможно, так как это
>   противоречит его деятельности (да и просто здравому смыслу). Поскольку
>   в российских источниках нет никаких ссылок на оригинал, с 99%
>   вероятностью речь идет об откровенном апокрифе.
>
> С уважением, Николай

Comment: Thanks you so much for such efforts. It is indeed interesting to hear the opinion of a real expert. But on the other hand, I just found that  that even Russia's president Vladimir Putin himself quoted Bismarck as saying that phrase! Links: https://snob.ru/selected/entry/86685 , https://irrussianality.wordpress.com/2017/12/16/crackpot-theory-no-9-assume-the-worst . I find it unthinkable that the Russian president will use made-up quotations. Do you think Putin is a liar?

Comment: Concerning Vlasov's opinion that the phrase does not make much sense, I found a history article about Bismarck that seems to say the opposite: >> *The most important constraint in international relations is, of course, the distribution of power. For structural realists, power is called capability. The term itself is etymologically derivative of “ability,” which implies what can, as opposed to what cannot, be done*.

Comment: *Joseph Parent and Joshua Baron observe that for classical realists, just like their contemporary cousins, “structure ruled … behavior was proportionate to power, and … interacting states had various appetites, but appetite was more a function of capability than taste.”* << Link: https://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/full/10.1162/isec_a_00323

Comment: @Mitsuko yes, putin is a liar, and this is the most innocuous of his lies, does it surprise you? in this particular case it's not really a lie, but an ignorance or simply going with the flow, he's just another Russian using popular aphorisms he's heard or read elsewhere

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка : Putin indeed did lie in the past, but I doubt he would lie by attributing a phrase to someone who did not say it. It just does not make sense to say a made-up quotation, because it is verifiable.

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка : Putin lived in Germany and speaks German well. He is a politician and must have studied a lot of historical materials. I feel the quotation is most likely based on a real phrase by Bismarck.

Comment: @Mitsuko: *>a history article about Bismarck that seems to say the opposite*   I'm neither Vlasov's nor Putin's advocate but I don't think you understood Vlasov's reply. Note that I asked him to comment on the quotation you provided in the Q., i.e. "Меня не интересуют их намерения, меня интересуют их возможности".   You might want to read [his research on another apocryphal quote](http://www.navlasov.ru/nauchnye-i-publicisticheskie-raboty/nauchnye-raboty/-nikogda-ne-voyuite-s-rossiei-otto-fon-b.html) from Bismark widely used. He mentions there one of the typical mechanisms of how such..

Comment: "quotations" come into existence. Anyway, I believe it's time to ask - **what on Earth does all this have to do with Russian language?**

Comment: My understanding of Vlasov's reply is that he finds the quotation provided in my question to be nonsensical and contradicting to actual actions by Bismarck. Did I get it wrong?

Comment: >> *what on Earth does all this have to do with Russian language?* << This quotation de facto became an aphorism in the Russian language. The aphorism is used in hunderds of websites, in a few books, in minutes of the Russian parliament. and even by Vladimir Putin himself. It is de facto an idiomatic expression or aphorism öf the Russian language. And this is why I felt entitled to ask about it on the Russian SE, especially as I got no answer on the German SE and on the History SE.

Comment: This aphorism is popular exclusively in the Russian language. It is a Russian thing, a Russian proverb, a Russian aphorism. It is attributed to Bismarck, but I do not know the actual origin. And this is what my question is about: What is the actual origin of that Russian aphorism?

Comment: @Mitsuko: *Did I get it wrong?*  Yes. There is a huge difference between `Расценивать такое высказывание, если оно и имело место, как некий общий принцип, которым руководствовался Бисмарк, попросту невозможно, так как это противоречит его деятельности (да и просто здравому смыслу).` and your `Vlasov's opinion that the phrase does not make much sense`. :)  People can't read your mind, they only see what you write and judge from that.

Comment: @tum_ : In Vlasov's statement, does the word "это" refer to "высказывание" or "pасценивать"?

Comment: @Mitsuko: "Это" refers to `Расценивать такое высказывание, … , как некий общий принцип, которым руководствовался Бисмарк`. In any case, this remark is sort of *on top* of what your original question was as you never asked about the political principles of Bismarck, you asked about the quotation only. Anyway, I think it's clear that if you strongly believe that Bismarck **did** say that, you would have to perform a **serious research** (i.e. not Google-only "research") to prove yourself right or otherwise. I don't think anyone else will do this. (I'll be offline for a while from now).

Answer (score 1):

As far as popularity is concerned, i don't recall ever coming across it.

One similar aphorism which i have heard being used and which according to sources does belong to him is

> Die Politik ist die Lehre vom Möglichen. - Политика есть искусство
>   возможного.

https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Otto_von_Bismarck#Quotes

The one you ask about doesn't seem to be mentioned amongst his quotes in Wikipedia, neither amongst the misattributed and disputed ones.

Comment: There are hundreds of hits in Google: https://www.google.com/search?ei=uBtEXfn5OOHSz7sPmoSluAU&q=%22%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82+%D0%B8%D1%85+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82+%D0%B8%D1%85+%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%22

Comment: @Mitsuko this still doesn't negate the fact of me never coming across it

Comment: I am not negating the fact of you not hearing that aphorism, but even your president used it, as I pointed out in an update to my question :)

Comment: @Mitsuko he's not my president, luckily, i never listen to speeches of politicians especially the Soviet, and i don't think there ever could be MY president

Comment: Are you not a Russian citizen? Or do you just not like what Putin does?

Comment: @Mitsuko both....

Comment: I guess you are likely to be Ukrainian then... Or to be a Russian who migrated from Russia and then chose another nationality...

Comment: @Mitsuko i do reside in Ukraine, let's put it this way